# How to make custom bitmap files 4bpp

Tags: python, bitmap

So I have written a program to make bitmap files and it is fully capable of doing 1 bit per pixel using the BITMAPCOREHEADER header (this is a learning project). But as soon as I try to implement 4 bits per pixel and add a red color into the color table everything stops working. Examples below in hex.

This is a working 1bpp 1 black pixel bitmap's data:

42 4D 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00

When I try to make it four bits per pixel to add red color it is an unsupported file type (changes in bold):

42 4D **27** 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 **24** 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 **04** 00 FF FF FF **FF 00 00 00 00 00** 00 **10** 00 00 00

Am I fundamentally not understanding how this file format works? Can I not just put arbitrary RGB's in the color table and reference them. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where is the code you have written?

Comment: @rustyhu the code isn't made yet. I'm testing it by writing the files from scratch so that I can work out how to do it in the code